# How to stop pytesseract from reading text

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I wanted to know a simple way to check if an image has text in python. I came across this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62145890/how-to-check-if-a-image-has-any-text-or-not), but it completely converts the image to text. Is there any way to make it "stop" if it encounters any text? Something like this would be great

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
image = cv2.imread('test.jpeg')
try:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
except TextEncountered:
    print('Text is found')
```

Comment: Anything usable in the pytesseract documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ ? What have you already tried? (I'm thinking image_to_osd *might* be faster?)

Comment: What you are looking for is text detection instead of full OCR. Take a look at https://github.com/argman/EAST

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make bounding box around text-areas in an image? (Even if text is skewed!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821969/how-to-make-bounding-box-around-text-areas-in-an-image-even-if-text-is-skewed)

Comment: While these techniques are possible, is there something that doesn't involve machine learning algorithms as I am trying to run it on a raspberry pi?

Comment: Tesseract itself has LSTM behind the scenes. You will need to do a lot of work to get an algorithm based on basic computer vision for text detection and it might be inaccurate. Best way is to use an inference API and run the model on a server.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the page segmentation mode parameter in the pytesseract.image_to_string function. This parameter tells pytesseract how to interpret the layout of the image. For example, if you set it to 6, it will assume that the image contains a single uniform block of text. If you set it to 7, it will assume that the image contains a single line of text. You can try different values to see which one works best for your images.

[You can find the full list of page segmentation modes in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828372/pytesseract-ocr-wrong-text-recognition).